# Send leakcanery trace to server

Tags: android, memory-leaks, leakcanary

I'm using leakcanery for a while now and it works fine! The thing is after testing one of my app on wide range of device some leaks showed up that i never saw them before so i decided to enable leakcanery in production version as well or trace of leaks to my server. 3 questions

1 - Will performance suffer?! Sometimes leakcanery causes some lags in debug mode, so if i enable in production version. does the same lags happen?

2 - I read the documentation on how to send heapfile to server but is there any way to send trace instead, like the once leakcanery normally shows. I  really don't want to analyse heapfile when i got it. so how can i parse this file before sending it to make something meaningful out of it?

3- I may be the dumest question but what should i do to enable leakcanery in production version? Is is enabled by default or should i config it some how?

Answer (score 0):

Part of the answer:

`debugCompile` is only for debug build and `releaseCompile` for production build.

```
dependencies {
    // Real LeakCanary for debug builds only: notifications, analysis, etc
   debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.3.1'

   // No-Op version of LeakCanary for release builds: no notifications, no analysis, nothing
   releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.3.1'
}
```